# Tables dissapearing after changing user in SQLDEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Why did all my tables disappear after changing the user? I created a new user and granted all privileges, but my database is empty after I log in with this new user ? If I log in with the original user they all come back, but I need to work with the tables with the new created user.
I know I can re-create them, but I would like to have them without doing this.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1692728/1509264

Comment: I was thinking of you 9 years ago when I wrote this blog post :) https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the connections tab, expand the connection and go to "Other Users" at the bottom of the list and you will see the list of users and, expanding those, their tables (and other objects) that you have at least the `SELECT` privilege on.

If you want to refer to tables owned by another user in a query then specify the schema name as well as the table name:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   other_schema.table_name;
```

Comment: @MT10 Thank you!  I did this ```alter session set current_schema = ion;
``` and now I can see the tables. The problem now is that I have a trigger that looks like this ```CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t12
    BEFORE CREATE OR DROP OR ALTER ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
  IF UPPER(USER) != 'ION' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20022, 'Only Ion can do LDD commands');
  END IF;
END;
/``` and the it won't trigger if I'm logged into the other user, I can create as many tables as I want. Why :( ?